# how to manage expiration date in quote object salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

How to add a validation rule that makes the quote expiration date not more than ten (10) days after the creation date of the quote?

what is the correct formula i should write in the condition formula field??

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have tried many and many formats to find out how to solve this issue and i found this 
line will solve the problem

```
IF((Expiration_Date__c >=  DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)+11), TRUE, FALSE)
```

and write the error message and in the case of true this message will be displayed

Answer (score -1):

Since expressions are boolean in Salesforce, as in most programming language, you can shorten this to (I also change >= to >, matter of taste):
Expiration_Date__c > DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)+10